# watershedding vs mean shift clustering

Tags: clustering

I'm working on a clustering problem, and I was trying to understand the difference between the [watershed algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29) and [mean shift clustering](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/26/mean-shift-clustering/). It seems that these algorithms are popular for image processing, but I was hoping to apply them to my non-image dataset (700,000 data points and 12 dimensions).

To prepare my data for watershedding, I was computing an N-dimensional histogram of my data points and then running a watershed algorithm on the histogram. It seems that both algorithms will assign a point to the cluster representing the nearest local maximum ("nearest" defined as using a gradient ascent).

I was hoping to better understand the fundamental differences between the algorithms, since they're always described as separate algorithms in the literature but I haven't been able to find a direct comparison of them.